# Error Happened when Update Database Using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

I add a new migration to my solution , and when trying to update database using this command

```
Update-Database
```

there is an error message shown

> There is already an object named 'Currency' in the database

I'm using Entity Framework Core 2.0

Answer (score 2):

As error says

**Someone added already added an object `Currency` in DB**

Seems there is a problem in migration process.

You can try following solution if they helps.

Run `add-migration` command in "**Package Manager Console**":

> Add-Migration First -IgnoreChanges

do some changes, and then update database from "Initial" file:

> Update-Database -verbose

If you are working on a Team Project. I will suggest you to set `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` to `false`

> AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;

It will ensure unpredictable migrations and make sure that every developer on the team works with the same data base structure.

You can also try

> `Update-Database -Script` for update a database manually. And you can exclude 'Currency' from resulting script

Comment: Add-Migration : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'IgnoreChanges'.
At line:1 char:23
+ Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Migration], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Add-Migration

Comment: try Executing `Add-Migration First -IgnoreChanges`

Comment: Try `Update-Database -Script` for update a database manually. And you can exclude 'Currency' from resulting script